# How to identify a call is disconnected when there are multiple calls in Android

Tags: java, android, telephonymanager

My problem is when i have multiple received calls (say 3 of 2 hold and 1 active), i don't get `CALL_STATE_IDLE` when the caller disconnect for any of the 2 calls. But get `CALL_STATE_IDLE` when last call is disconnected. `CALL_STATE_RINGING` & `CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK` works fine.

```
public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
 super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);
 Log.e("MyService", "Switch " + state);
switch (state) {

case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
    Log.e("MyService", "CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK");
    break;

case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
    Log.e("MyService", "CALL_STATE_RINGING");
    break;

case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
    Log.e("MyService", "CALL_STATE_IDLE");
    break;

default:
    Log.e("MyService", "default");
    break;
}
}
```

Comment: It should be 2 of 3 hold and 1 active :)

Comment: It will be two. But how this two comes at the third call disconnection moment. That is my question

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is not an answer to solve your problem. But, it definitely adds value to the solution

> What is CALL_STATE_IDLE ?

Device call state: No activity.

So, we shouldn't expect it to send CALL_STATE_IDLE state when there is an active line. That's why the event CALL_STATE_IDLE is broadcasted only when all the calls are disconnected